# php search results page yielding non "eye" appealing data

Tags: php, css, forms, format

So I finnaly got my php database search to function properly but im unaware of how to format it to make it look nicer.

Currently my echo code is

```
 echo "<p><h3>".$results['lfname']."</h3>".$results['id'].$results['phonenum'].$results['state'].$results['zip']."</p>";
```

and the data i receive is like

```
John Doe    
12507(704) 372-2622NC28031
```

I would like the data to be like

```
John Doe   12507   
(704) 372-2622   NC   28031
```

or something of that sort. Do you guys know how i could format this properly or any links to any pages where i could learn how to format this results. Wasn't sure of what to google since im not sure of the rules and limits of php pages.
Thanks again

Comment: Use some spaces `." ".` and break tags `."<br>".`

Comment: break the `h3` out of the `p` tag

Comment: those worked. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, it is ill-advised to wrap a heading Tag within a Paragraph tag. 
Secondly, the ID is outside the < h3 > Tag. And since < h3 > is a block-level Element, You shouldn't expect its contents to be on the same Level as the ID. Here's what may help:

```
            <!-- TO STYLE THE CSS CLASSES, AT THE TOP OF YOUR FILE WITHIN THE HEAD SECTION-->
            <!-- DO LIKE SO -->
            <style type="text/css">
                .full-name{
                    font-weight: 900;    /*CAN BE NORMAL, BOLD OR BOLDER OR USE NUMBERS FROM 100 TO 900*/
                    color: #613ac5;       /* USE YOUR PREFERRED COLOR */
                    font-size: 12px;      /* AGAIN CHANGE TO YOUR DESIRED FONT-SIZE */
                }
                .result-id{
                    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: normal;  /*CAN BE NORMAL, BOLD OR BOLDER OR USE NUMBERS FROM 100 TO 900*/
                    color: #8c0210;       /* USE YOUR PREFERRED COLOR */
                    font-size: 12px;      /* AGAIN CHANGE TO YOUR DESIRED FONT-SIZE */
                }

                .right-spaced{
                    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    display:inline-block;
                    padding-right: 15px;
                    font-weight: normal;  
                    color: #8c0210;    
                    font-size: 12px;     
                }
            </style>


        <?php

            $strOutput    =  "<h3 class='full-name'> " . $results['lfname'] ."<span class='result-id'> {$results['id']}</span></h3>";
            $strOutput   .= "<p><span class='phone right-spaced'>{$results['phonenum']}</span>";
            $strOutput   .= "<span class='state right-spaced'>{$results['state']}</span>";
            $strOutput   .= "<span class='zip right-spaced'>{$results['zip']}</span>";
            $strOutput   .= "</p>";
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the font type/style, like bold or italic, of an individual result

Comment: @WChampion    Exactly... That is why you have the class there... The Post has been updated to reflect that....

Comment: sweet thanks man. Just stared working with code 5 days ago and as an intern for my dads company he has me trying to build him a employee database app that he could check via his phone but i haven't got that far yet. Any constructive criticism is always welcome

Comment: @WChampion   ***You can't constructively criticize a grain of Corn you planted 5 Days ago that is barely growing***. The only thing you can do is **Feed it instead: with Water & Manure and make sure it gets enough Sunlight...**  In your case; never be afraid to make mistakes... Break the Rules, try something Crazy. Mess with Codes.... get annoyed... clench your Fists and bite your Nails... then learn... that is the way... learn and learn... **The Corn also breaks the ground to push its way above it, to the Surface.** Good Luck to you and I believe Daddy will be Proud, someday Soon!!!

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
echo "<h3>{$results['lfname']} {$results['id']}</h3>";
echo "<p>{$results['phonenum']} {$results['state']} {$results['zip']}</p>";
```

All I've done is reorder the array indexes and I've used a different way of echoing array values (which I personally find much <del>nicer</del> more readable than dropping in and out of strings with `" . $blah['foo']. "`)

Comment: nice, thanks mate. now would it be possible to enclose each set of results in its on box of some sort. Say i Search for john and have 3 Johns. could each set be outlined?

Comment: It most certainly can be.. I'd recommend looking at mozilla's HTML and CSS guides [on the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org), specifically I think you'll be interested in the [div tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) and the [css borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) pages